# Loading/Modifying/Saving Changes to Text File

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Allow me to start by sharing what I have so far:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do contents <- readFile "filmList.txt"
      let database = (read contents :: [Film])
      putStr "Please enter your username: "
      userName <- getLine
      menu database        
      where menu newDb = do putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                            putStrLn "1: Display all films currently in the database"
                            putStrLn "2: Add a new film to the database (and display all films)"
                            putStrLn "3: "
                            putStrLn "4: Save Database"
                            putStrLn "5: Exit"
                            putStr "\nSelected option: "
                            option <- getLine
                            case option of "1" -> putStrLn(displayFilms newDb)
                                           "2" -> do putStr "Name of film: "
                                                     title <- getLine
                                                     putStr "Name of director: "
                                                     director <- getLine
                                                     putStr "Year of release: "
                                                     year <- getLine
                                                     putStrLn(displayFilms (addNewFilm title director (read year) newDb))
                            menu newDb
```

## `

I have managed to load a txt file with the database of Film types but I cannot figure out how to go about actually making changes to the data. When I try to run option 2, I get a list of all the films with the newly added one as well but if I then run option 1 to list all films, it doesn't include the newly added film. Should I be saving back to the txt file each time a new Film instance is added? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that everything in Haskell is immutable. When you write `addNewFilm (addNewFilm title director (read year) newDb`, that doesn't *change* the database represented by `newDb` to include the new information; it merely returns a *new* database that has all the old information plus the new row. It's your responsibility to choose where and when to use the old database (named, ironically, `newDb`) or the new one returned by the function.

For example, you might write this `case` instead:

```
case option of "1" -> putStrLn (displayFilms newDb) >> menu newDb
               "2" -> do ...
                         let evenMoreReallyNewDb = addNewFilm title director (read year) newDb
                         putStrLn (displayFilms evenMoreReallyNewDb)
                         menu evenMoreReallyNewDb
```

You might notice that both cases end with a very similar pattern (a `putStrLn . displayFilms` and then a `menu`). Unifying them would be a good idea; see if you can see how to do that yourself.

If you want to write the modified database back to the file, you will of course need to do that explicitly using `writeFile` or a similar function.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I have managed to solve that issue now, and am able to save to txt file nicely as well. However, I have been looking up what you mentioned about unifying the repetitive code. How would you recommend I go about doing this? I cannot seem to find anything useful online about going about this. Perhaps I need to search in the right places. Could you give me some advice on this? I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @KieranEdwards Consider defining another function `menuWithPrint db = putStrLn (displayFilms db) >> menu db` and calling that, instead of duplicating the code in both branches.

Comment: Also, if you want to write more idiomatic code in the future, learn about monad transformers.  Your code would be much more simpler if you used the `StateT [Film] IO ()` monad.  First you have to learn about the [State monad](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/5406.html) and then learn about [monad transformers](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.pdf).